# Google Charts creating relative URL

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts, and i notice that the URL of the chart is a relative URL. 
Example: //chart.googleapis.com instead of https://chart.googleapis.com

If i create a single HTML file with the chart code, the URL is fine (with the https), but in a file served by a PHP application, the URL is relative.

In normal situations this would not be a problem, but i'm exporting the chart to a PDF, and without the full url the chart is not rendered on the PDF.. Has anyone had the same problem ?

The working example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['imagesparkline']});
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>


<script>
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Revenue', 'Licenses'],
    [435, 132],
    [438, 131],
    [512, 137],
    [460, 142],
    [491, 140],
    [487, 139],
    [552, 147],
    [511, 146],
    [505, 151],
    [509, 149]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ImageSparkLine(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, {width: 120, height: 40, showAxisLines: false,  showValueLabels: false, labelPosition: 'left'});
  }
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle with the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/br6837oq/

**SOLUTION**

Solved this replacing the relative URL by the absolute one:

`$html = str_replace('src="//chart.googleapis.com', 'src="https://chart.googleapis.com', $html);`

Comment: The problem is not how i export the pdf. I solved the problem with a simples function: `$html = str_replace('src="//chart.googleapis.com', 'src="https://chart.googleapis.com', $html);`